# How to install a new Ghost theme on hostghost.io?

Tags: installation, themes, blogs, ghost-blog

I just purchased a hosting of Ghost blog on http://hostghost.io and wish to change the theme from Casper theme to different one (i.e. Ghostwritter). I am able to download some from Marketplace (http://marketplace.ghost.org) but I cannot see any option at the hostghost.io administration that would allow me to upload it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, you cannot change the theme of a Ghost blog hosted on Host Ghost (http://hostghost.io).

The service is still in beta and the ability to change themes is scheduled for a future update. It's not prominently displayed on the site itself, but if you hit the button to sign up for the beta, the popup requesting your email, etc. you'll also find this in the column on the right:

> *Coming soon - (c. Nov 1)*
>
> • Access to FTP to manage & upload themes

They should mention it in their FAQ section.

Answer (score 0):

Might want to look at your own hosted Ghost blog - plenty of guides listed at http://ghost.centminmod.com/how-to-install-ghost-blogging-platform/